# "programming robotics with ros" Cmakelist.txt not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Respected,
I am following the book "programming robotics with ros". To begin with this, i simple git cloned the github source of the book but on performing the command "catkin-make" , i am getting the following error:

[image: image description]

This is the github link i am following "https://github.com/osrf/rosbook"
Here, the folders within the "code" lack a cmakelist.txt file.
I tried to remove the "code" folder from the package and simply added the code files in other folders of the package, and that is performing the "catkin_make" command but then the the individual files of the code folder are not working.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253986/%22programming-robotics-with-ros%22-cmakelist.txt-not-found/) by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you check [errata to the book](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920024736)?

It says:

> ...
> Assuming (as in Chapter 2) your workspace is ~/catkin_ws, the following commands would create a basics package in that workspace that depends on rospy:

```
user@hostname$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src 
user@hostname$ catkin_create_pkg basics rospy
```

> The examples and discussion in Chapter 3 should then work as expected, in the ~/catkin_ws/src/basics directory.
> The other way to make the examples work in this chapter, besides typing them in manually, is to clone this entire repository; then you will have the basics directory (with all the examples) that you can symlink into your workspace. For example, assuming there is an existing workspace in ~/catkin_ws

```
user@hostname$ git clone https://github.com/osrf/rosbook ~/rosbook 
user@hostname$ ln -s ~/rosbook/code/basics ~/catkin_ws/src 
user@hostname$ cd ~/catkin_ws 
user@hostname$ catkin_make
```

> (that last step will ensure there is a valid setup file for this workspace created in ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash) Then you can source the setup file of that workspace: user@hostname$ . ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash and the examples should work.

Personally I would advise following the first snippet with creating a catkin package as it is way cleaner than the other approach.

---

Originally posted by [msadowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/19897/msadowski/) with karma: 311 on 2017-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-02-12**:
Thank you for the help.
it solved my issue.

Regards